# Как пишутся неформальные названия игровых приставок (консолей)?

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, кавычки

Возьмём игровую приставку Sony PlayStation (любого поколения). Неформально её частенько называют *сонькой* или *плойкой*. Как тогда пишутся эти слова, нужны ли прописные буквы, кавычки; какое правило тут применимо?